# Is "approve" required only for transferring tokens? Not a native coin?

Tags: tokens, security, decentralized-exchange, transfer, erc-20-approve

Speaking of Ethereum blockchain, or any other one compatible with it: Polygon, Avalanche and others: is calling the function `approve(...)` mandatory **only, and only,** when  there's a token involved in `transfer/tranferFrom`?

Or is it **also** required for the native coin - ETH (AVAX, MATIC respectufully)? And if not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `approve` function is an explicit function in an ERC20 token contract (and is part of the ERC20 standard). It's used when transferring ERC20 tokens indirectly - if direct `transfer` is used then `approve` is not needed.

The native asset (such as Ether) can only be transferred directly and it does not have a related contract. All of its functionality is built-in and it always works the same, regardless of where it's used. So, `approve` is related only to ERC20 token standard (and some other standards), not to the native asset.

Comment: more precisely: `approve` is required ONLY a) for ERC20 tokens b) when `transferFrom(..)` is used?

Comment: Well, other token standards also use `approve`, but otherwise both points are correct.